# Problem with webhooks and the role/permissions idea

Tags: discord, discord.js

I develop a bot with discord.js that uses things like `msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")` or `msg.member.roles.cache.has(teacherRoleID)`. Everything worked fine until I tried webhooks. By adding these two lines :

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setStatus("online")
  client.user.setActivity("!help", {
    type: "PLAYING",
  });
  superConsole(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag} in ${client.guilds.size} guilds!`);


    const hook = new Discord.WebhookClient("ID", "secret token"); // THESE
    hook.send("I am now alive!");                                 // LINES

  });
```

(btw *superConsole* is a function)
Since then, the program did not work any more and always returned the same errors: `(node:20736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of null` & `(node:20736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null`

When I delete these 2 lines for the webhook, it works again. Why? I don't understand.

The permission and role things are in a message listener:

```js
client.on('message', async msg => {
if (msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') {
// some stuff here
}
if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(teacherRoleID) {
// some stuff here
}
});
```

Comment: Could you please show the code where you used `msg.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")` and `msg.member.roles.cache.has(teacherRoleID)`?

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include that code? It's easier than trying to update your question with code in the comments.

Comment: i've just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you send a message from `hook`, it triggers the client's `message` event. Because a webhook isn't a guild member, `msg.member` will get `undefined` for messages sent from a webhook.

You would have to use something like this:

```js
if (msg.member) {
  if (msg.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR') {
    // some stuff here
  }
  if (msg.member.roles.cache.has(teacherRoleID) {
  // some stuff here
  }
}
```